# SSIS - A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've a simple SSIS Package to transfer data between two servers, let's say from SERVER01 (source) to SERVER02 (destination). When I test my SSIS package localy everything works great. When I deploy it on the SERVER02 it fails with an error:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)

So I tested my "select query" directly in SSMS: Execute on my laptop - ok. Execute in SSMS on SERVER02 - fails with same error message. Execute on other servers - ok.

So it means it's related to the SERVER02. It's virtual machine running Windows 2012 and SQL Server 2012. I can ping the SERVER01 without any problems. The data is about 170.000 rows and 20 columns.

The query breaks after some time, and it's random. Sometimes I get 10.000 records before it breaks, sometimes 80.000

Can someone point me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you reach both servers from place you are running your package?

Comment: yes - I can run other smaller queries without any problems. I forgot to mention that the query breaks after some time, and it's random. Sometimes I get 10.000 records before it breaks, sometimes 80.000.

Comment: try to run the query within the sql server goes the same then your virtual needs more memory, or you having trouble in your connectivity

Comment: we've 4GB free RAM (from 16GB). When I run the query memory usage doesn't change (70%)

Comment: was one time for me, the small querys was OK, but if i inserted large query even without running it (or sometimes running) sql server give this error. In my case the IT Administrators disablead antivirus in windows server where sql server was intalled and then was ok.

Answer (score 0):

IS SERVER01 defined as a linked server on SERVER02? Has the user that the package is executing as got correct permissions on relevant objects?

Consider the connection timeout property in the connection manager.

Comment: no, it wasn't. I just added the SERVER01 as linkedserver on SERVER02, but I've same result as before - query breaks after some time. User has all permissions, I can run other smaller queries without any issues.

Comment: try to increase the memory allotted to virtual machine

Comment: we've 4GB free RAM (from 16GB). When I run the query memory usage doesn't change (70%)